# How to quickly open an application for the 2nd time via Dash?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, unity-dash

When I want to open an application via Dash, I just hit <kbd>Super</kbd>, type the first letters, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. For instance: <kbd>Super</kbd>, "drop", <kbd>Enter</kbd>  to start Dropbox. However, if I want to start an application again, Dash remembers it, but I cannot start it by hitting <kbd>ENTER</kbd> although "drop" is still in there, and Dropbox is in the first position. Why?

How can I (without using the mouse) start an application again?

UPDATE:

**better example** (hopefully):

1. <kbd>Super</kbd> ... type "ged" ... <kbd>Enter</kbd> to start Gedit
2. close Gedit
3. <kbd>Super</kbd> ... and now? "ged" is remembered, Gedit is still in pole position ready to be started. However, hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> does not work.

How can I start an application again? - Without using the mouse or retyping?

If I have to retype, it makes no sense that Dash remembers the application and my typed letters. I assume there is a way to open the application again by just: <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or something similar). Thanks!

Comment: If I already have firefox running and, hit 'super' type `firefox` and hit 'Enter' it opens a new window...

Comment: Dropbox is a strange app to use an example. Can you suggest another one? I have dropbox running all the time and wouldn't expect a second copy. As iSeth says, firefox, nautilus, sudoko all start another window as expected.

Comment: I think that that behavior is dropbox specific, because your desired behavior works for me for programs such as the terminal, open office, etc... i can just hit super -> enter and it will open a new windows of the last opened app

Comment: question updated

Comment: Works for me. Super followed by ged followed by Enter started gedit. Close gedit. now Super followed by Enter starts gedit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed previous answer as I was on 13.04

As far as 12.10 - As long as the mouse cursor isn't in the Dash when you re-open the Dash then the previous search should still be active, (blinking curosr bar) & enter should again open your 1st listed app

Comment: Thanks! The mouse was the problem. But it shouldn't. This would mean that on a small screen it will never work since the Dash will always overlap with the mouse.

Comment: I had started a bug on before noticing it was the mouse cursor posistion. But that actually makes it a 'bug', to track - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1084267